# JQuery mobile not loading ajax links

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a link in a javascript file that is running successfully when loaded. The issue I have is that when someone clicks the link, JQM does not load it with AJAX, but rather loads it in a new page. I do not understand why this is happening.

Here is the HTML for the link:

```
boxText.innerHTML = "<a href='../home-details/index.php?id=" + home_id + "' class='infowindow'>" + address + "<div class='infowindow-arrow'></div></a>";
```

Here is the flow of pages:
Index page -> Map page that renders markers when the page is loaded. The markers have infowindows that have a link as content. These also load when the markers are created. The infowindow link does not load using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what you see in inspector?  jQuery will be dynamically be applying classes and such, as described in the documentation:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

> **Linking without Ajax**
>   Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions, the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax behavior.

Comment: I took a look at using inspector, and the links are not wrapped in anything from jquery mobile, just google maps. Is there a way to listen for the click event and get jquery mobile to load it using ajax? I believe that would work.

Comment: are you seeing rel="external" or data-ajax="false" on the <a> in the inspector?  Can you post what you see in the inspector?

Comment: Here is a screenshot because copying out of the inspector is rough: http://grab.by/e9w0

Comment: If instead of drawing the link through .innerHTML you draw it statically (just for testing) does the link still fail to load through AJAX?

Comment: If I draw the link statically, JQM wraps it properly. Using innerHTML it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Are only dynamically created links doing full reload?

If not, then jQM IS using AJAX. You see new address in url bar because you are probably using a browser that supports pushstate method (webkit, mozilla). jQM is AJAX loading the page, and then changing address in URL bar without actually loading the page.

You can check this by opening your page in IE9. It does not support pushstate yet, so you will get the hashtag url you are expecting.

You can change this behavior by setting jQM option `pushStateEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: Its using ajax from the index to the map page. But the links on the map page are doing loading using ajax.